# Is there any alternative to jQuery function that's limit the checkbox type selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a jQuery function to limit the checkbox selection to 4 items no more, the problem is: it's only works with tag input by itself! but when i put this tag inside a  or inside a  for table, it doesn't work!

I have tried remove the  tag, makes the jQuery method works with no problem, but in implementation i need this tag to show my items in a table.

This is my html code:

```
<c:forEach var="tempVehicles" items="${vehicleList}">
     <tr>
         <c:choose>
              <c:when test="${tempVehicles.vehicleType eq vehicleType}">
                    <td>${tempVehicles.registration}  </td>
                    <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="vIds[]" name="vIds[]" value="${tempVehicles.id}"/></td>
              </c:when>
          </c:choose>
     </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

and my jQuery code:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {

    var limit = 4;

    if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {

        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

With this code, i can select more than 4 elements 'the jQuery method doesn't work', but when i remove the `<td>` tag from the input, the method actually works.

Comment: possibly because your inputs are not `.siblings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input's are not siblings, change the selector for checking how many are selected as in the following code

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {

    var limit = 4;

    if($('.single-checkbox:checked').length >= limit) {

        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
  <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1"/></td>
  <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2"/></td>
  <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3"/></td>
  <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4"/></td>
  <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="5"/></td>
  <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="6"/></td>
  <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="7"/></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, your solution actually works. Appreciate it.

Comment: I wouldn't post it as an answer if it didn't work @AdamObaidi :p

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the inputs are children of `td`s - they aren't siblings, so `.siblings` isn't going to select the right elements.

If they all have the same class of `single-checkbox`, then put the `.single-checkbox`es into a jQuery collection, and in the callback, check if that collection's length, filtered by `:checked`, is greater than `limit`:

```js
const $singleCheckbox = $('input.single-checkbox');
$singleCheckbox.on('change', function(e) {
  var limit = 4;
  if ($singleCheckbox.filter(':checked').length > limit) {
    this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="vIds[]" name="vIds[]" value="${tempVehicles.id}" /></td>
    <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="vIds[]" name="vIds[]" value="${tempVehicles.id}" /></td>
    <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="vIds[]" name="vIds[]" value="${tempVehicles.id}" /></td>
    <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="vIds[]" name="vIds[]" value="${tempVehicles.id}" /></td>
    <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="vIds[]" name="vIds[]" value="${tempVehicles.id}" /></td>
    <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="vIds[]" name="vIds[]" value="${tempVehicles.id}" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can impose a check-limit by going up to the parent and then querying back down to its children.

```js
(($) => {
  $.fn.checkLimit = function(limit) {
    this.on('change', function(e) {
      let $parent = $(this).parent();
      let $target = $parent.prop('tagName') === 'LABEL' ? $parent.parent() : $parent;
      if ($target.find(':checked').length > limit) {
        this.checked = false;
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$('input[name="vIds[]"]').checkLimit(4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Mark-up via: https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/checkbox/same-name-group.php -->
<form action="#" method="post" class="demoForm" id="demoForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Demo: Checkboxes Sharing Same Name</legend>
    <p>Check the types of sports or fitness activities you engage in on a regular basis.</p>
    <p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vIds[]" value="cycling" /> cycling</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vIds[]" value="running" /> running</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vIds[]" value="visit gym" /> visit gym</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vIds[]" value="swimming" /> swimming</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vIds[]" value="team sports" /> team sport(s)</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="vIds[]" value="other" /> other</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```